# Pointers ignoring unsigned trait in C?

Tags: c

I'm curious why the following code returns negative numbers even though every single variable and fuction initialization in this program is an unsigned int. I thought they always were supposed to be positive?.

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int main ()
{
unsigned int ch = 0;
unsigned int asteriskValue = 0;
while(ch!=27)
{
    ch = getch();
        if (ch == 224)
        {
            increaseDecrease(&asteriskValue);
        }
    printf("%d",asteriskValue);
}
}

void increaseDecrease(unsigned int *value)
{
unsigned int upOrDown;
upOrDown = getch ();
if(upOrDown == 72)
    (*value)--;
else if(upOrDown == 80)
    (*value)++;
}
```

Comment: `unsigned` integers are not only positive, but can also be `0`. Using The wrong format-specifier invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: `unsigned` is not a trait, but a type specifier. C does not support traits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your results is really a positive value, but printing it with a "%d" flag, tells printf to interpret it as a signed value, as if you were casting on the fly the type: (signed)asteriskValue

Try printing it with a "%u" formatting instead of "%d".

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot! but if i dont print the value and use it for computing the (*value)-- still decrements asteriskValue down to -1. How can i force it to stay as a unsigned, similar to const with variables?

Comment: In fact, you'll never have -1,  it will becomes 65535 (for example, if your in 16 bits), but printing it as a signed will make you think you've got -1...

Comment: You found the mistake but not the right rationale. printf doesn't cast its arguments, it doesn't even know what they are. If you use the wrong format specifier it is just undefined behaviour.